# Using enum in drools

Tags: drools, optaplanner, drools-planner

I am solving an employee rostering problem. One of the constraints there is that Employee from each "type" should be present on every day. Type is defined as an enum.

I have right now configured this rule as follows:

```
rule "All employee types must be covered"
when
    not Shift(employeeId != null, $employee: getEmployee(), $employee.getType() == "Developer")
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end
```

This works fine. However I would have to configure a similar rule for all possible employee types.

To generalize it, I tried this:

```
rule "All employee types must be covered"
when
    $type: Constants.EmployeeType()
    not Shift(employeeId != null, $employee: getEmployee(), $employee.getType() == $type.getValue())
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end
```

However, this rule doesn't get executed. Below is my enum defined in Constants file

```
public enum EmployeeType {
    Developer("Developer"),
    Manager("Manager");

    private String value;

    Cuisine(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are never inserting the enums in your session (they are not facts).
One way to solve it is to manually insert them:

```
for(EmployeeType type : Constants.EmployeeType.values()){
  ksession.insert(type);
}
```

Another way is to make your rule fetch all the possible values from the enum:

```
rule "All employee types must be covered"
when
  $type: Constants.EmployeeType() from Constants.EmployeeType.values()       
  not Shift(employeeId != null, $employee: getEmployee(), $employee.getType() == $type.getValue())

then
  scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The rule I've written missed checking the "date" part of it. Every shift has a string date assigned to it. And I have a List of date strings for which I am trying to come up with the roster assignment.
How can I iterate over the date string in the rule?

Comment: One idea would be to put the list of dates in a class, insert an object of that class into the session and use it in your rules. I would suggest you to create a new question in SO.

Comment: I posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044004/optaplanner-iterate-over-list-variable-in-drools-rule-file
No answers yet.